# Runnable class using boost:thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, c++11, boost

**EDIT > [This tutorial](http://antonym.org/2009/05/threading-with-boost---part-i-creating-threads.html) provides a good answer**

How can I use `boost::thread` to make a class runnable?

```
class Hello
{
    void run();
    bool canRun();
    boost::condition_variable cond;
    boost::mutex mut;
};

Hello::run()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(this->mut);
    while (!this->canRun())
        this->cond.wait(lock);
    // do my stuff
}
```

I don't know if I should inherit `boost::thread`, have a `boost::thread` attribute in my class...

I want to be able to do it like this:

```
Hello hello = Hello();

hello.run();

hello.stop();
```

Comment: Why would you do that? A few languages create "runnable" classes *because they can't express threads better*. C++ can, and Boost *does*. You don't need to emulate the API flaws from other languages. Having to inherit from some "Runnable" base class in order to start a thread is a horrible design. The sane design is what Boost has: you create a thread object by passing it the function (or function object) it should run.

Comment: What's the problem if my thread is living inside my class and if I pass it my class run() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should just put a thread instance inside your class, and in your run() method you can start the thread (with another member function of course).  In stop() you can call thread::join() after setting `canRun = false`.

Comment: Ok perfect, that easy. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, why not :) 
See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3155e1031b8e4a5)**

It's c++03 compatible.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

struct Hello
{
    void run();
    bool canRun() { return true; }
    boost::condition_variable cond;
    boost::mutex mut;
};

void Hello::run()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(this->mut);
    cond.wait(lock, boost::bind(&Hello::canRun, this));

    std::cout << "Done";
}

int main()
{
    Hello obj;
    boost::thread th(&Hello::run, &obj);

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));

    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(obj.mut);
        obj.cond.notify_one();
    }

    th.join(); 
}
```

Note that I used the predicated version of `wait()` to await the start condition.

Comment: You need not lock any mutex to notify a condition variable, indeed it wastes a tiny bit of CPU capacity to wake up a thread waiting on the condition variable only to have it immediately block on the mutex that you are holding.

Comment: @Casey In general, you're somewhat right that you don't need to hold the lock _here_, while notifying the single thread. However, I don't think you can claim the bad performance. It's up to the (OS) implementation how it manages the waking up. At the very least, the  `pthreads` documentation very clearly intends conditions to be signaled under the mutex lock.

Comment: _The pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() functions may be called by a thread whether or not it currently owns the mutex that threads calling pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() have associated with the condition variable during their waits; however, if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() - [posix man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html)_

Comment: In general, I usually show the lock in my examples, because **(a)** it is safer (condition variables most often synchronize access to some shared state, imagine - for the OP's case - the implementation of `carRun()`) **(b)** it is more generally correct (the scheduling priorities with multiple waiters) **(c)** thread checking tools like DRBD/Helgrind cannot otherwise provide reliable diagnostics.